# Why there is no Debug configuration in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I downloaded the source code of a Visual Studio 2010 project, and since I have to analyze it for my University I'd like to be able to debug with breakpoints

Problem is, my Configuration popup only shows Release as option, there is no Debug option and so my breakpoints are always ignored

This is the first time I try to use VS, I always used Eclipse as IDE and I really don't know how to solve this - I tried to search the web but it didn't help

So, how can I run a VS project in debug with my breakpoints?
Thanks in advance

If it can help, here's the project - http://scene.sourceforge.net/download.html

EDIT

If it can helps, when I try to debug in existing configuration a pop up warns me that ( loosely translated from italian, not the exact sentence ) "Debug informations related to project not found. Binary not compilated with debug informations".

Answer (score 0):

A VS project can hold many configurations, not just the default Win32 Debug and Release. It's also possible to delete existing configurations which is probably your case.

You can add the Debug configuration by right clicking on the solution within VS and select **Build Configuration**. Select new and ask to copy from Release.

Manually change the build options to a debug build which time consuming BTW. You'll need to go over each and every option.

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence please? I tried to simply create a new configuration called Debug, but it seems like it's just a copy of the previous configuration, it still doesn't see my breakpoints. What else should I  change?